# and/where condition not working after join

Tags: mysql

Can't figure out how to add a condition after the last inner join. The last condition lc.unsubscribed_c <> 1 not working.. I also tried AND. No sure how to get it to work.

```
SELECT 
l.first_name,
l.last_name,
lc.code_c,
lc.unsubscribed_c,
ea.email_address
FROM email_addr_bean_rel eabr
JOIN email_addresses ea
ON eabr.email_address_id = ea.id
AND eabr.deleted = 0
JOIN leads l
ON eabr.bean_id = l.id
AND l.deleted = 0
INNER JOIN
leads_cstm lc ON l.id = lc.id_c
WHERE
lc.unsubscribed_c <> 1
```

Comment: ... what's not working?

Comment: What is your input / output? Any fiddle would be useful to get the actual picture of your problem.

Comment: Does lc.unsubscribed_c permit NULL ?

Comment: The query produces 0 results with the added WHERE condition on the end, without it, working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
l.first_name,
l.last_name,
lc.code_c,
lc.unsubscribed_c,
ea.email_address
FROM email_addr_bean_rel eabr
JOIN email_addresses ea ON eabr.email_address_id = ea.id
JOIN leads l ON eabr.bean_id = l.id
INNER JOIN leads_cstm lc ON l.id = lc.id_c
WHERE
lc.unsubscribed_c <> 1
AND eabr.deleted = 0
AND l.deleted = 0
```

Comment: no error message, just 0 results, and pretty much all rows have unsubscribed field set to 0